# Resolving ambiguity with using declaration

Tags: c++

Look at this snippet:

```
namespace A {
int fn();
}
namespace B {
int fn();
}

// namespace Ns {

using namespace A;
using namespace B;
using A::fn;

int z = fn();

// }
```

This code doesn't compile, as `fn()` is ambiguous at `int z = fn();`

If I put `using`'s and `z` into a namespace (remove the two `//`), the code compiles. Why is that? What is special about the global namespace?

Comment: `z = A::fn();` in your case, right?

Comment: @George That comment makes no sense. The OP doesn't have or want any function in the global namespace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [namespace.udir]/2

> A *using-directive* specifies that the names in the nominated namespace can be used in the scope in which the
>   *using-directive* appears after the *using-directive*. During unqualified name lookup (3.4.1), the names appear
>   as if they were declared in the nearest enclosing namespace which contains both the *using-directive* and the
>   nominated namespace.

Thus, when you have the namespace `Ns`, the directives `using namespace A;` and `using namespace B` make `A::fn` and `B::fn` appear in the global namespace, whereas `using A::fn;` makes `fn` appear in `Ns`. The latter declaration "wins" during name lookup.

Comment: Indeed, and this is also how the global namespace isn't special (to be explicit for the OP): you can see this by putting a `namespace Foo { ... }` around the whole file, making `A` and `B` nested namespaces. The behaviour won't change.

Comment: Thanks Brian! What could be the rationale behind this behavior? It seems a little strange to me. It happens to solve my case, I can choose which `fn()` wins. Could it be the reason?

Comment: @geza I don't know the rationale. If you asked another question then I bet someone would know the answer

Comment: I thought about this a little bit. At first sight, `using namespace` should "import" all stuff from the namespace as if everything were using declared. But this could be a bad idea, because then I couldn't add anything in my namespace which has the same name as anything in the "imported" namespace. This may be the reason, but who knows :)