# Why can't I use foo::bar functions within sub::bar when using namespace foo?

Tags: c++, scope, namespaces, language-lawyer

Consider the following program:

```
namespace foo {
namespace sub {
int f();
} // namespace sub 
} // namespace foo 

namespace bar {
namespace sub {

int g()  {
    using namespace foo;
    return sub::f() + 1;
}

} // namespace sub 
} // namespace bar
```

I expect this to compile, but - it doesn't:

```
$ g++-6 -c a.cpp
a.cpp: In function ‘int bar::sub::g()’:
a.cpp:12:9: error: ‘f’ is not a member of ‘bar::sub’
  return sub::f() + 1;
         ^~~
a.cpp:12:9: note: suggested alternative:
a.cpp:3:5: note:   ‘foo::sub::f’
 int f();
     ^
```

no luck with clang either:

```
$ clang++-6.0 -c a.cpp
a.cpp:12:9: error: no member named 'f' in namespace 'bar::sub'; did you mean 'foo::sub::f'?
        return sub::f() + 1; 
               ^~~~~~
               foo::sub::f
a.cpp:3:5: note: 'foo::sub::f' declared here
int f();
    ^
1 error generated.
```

and it *knows* which function I want, too!

Now, I understand that things could be ambiguous if I had both a `foo::sub::f` and a `bar::sub::f` here. But - why is `bar::sub` "hiding" `foo::sub` even when I explicitly ask to use `foo::sub` functions?

To be clear about what an answer might:

- An explanation why this is the (most) reasonable behavior and my expectation is unreasonable.
- The rationale for it being this way in the C++ standard.
- A quotation from standard saying this needs to be the case; maybe the context will help me understand why this was decided.

Motivation: I've written my code so that the last namespace before the function is  part of the method name, in the sense that you wouldn't understand what the function does without prepending the namespace. So instead of saying `sub_f()` like I would in `C`, I want to be able to say `sub::f()`. It's proving difficult to do so without prepending a much longer path of namespaces.

Comment: The two similar `sub` are confusing, and you could have similar functions there. I think the compilers are correct in telling you to be explicit (despite the `using namespace foo`).

Comment: you are not really explicitly asking for `foo::sub`, you are just asking to find a `sub::f` which happens to be in `foo`

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: 1. I am being explicit - I've said I wanted to use `foo::sub` functions. I can't be more explicit than that without going to the single function level.  2. There can be no confusion if function names don't clash - at least when I've been explicit.

Comment: @user463035818: It just happens to be in the namespace I explicitly said I want to look for functions in, you mean. But, more importantly, how would I be able to refer to `foo:sub::f` as `sub::f` if not the way I'm doing it now?

Comment: You are not explicitly asking to use `foo::sub`, you have just imported `namespace foo`. That's very different. If you want to be explicit, then use `foo::sub::f`. That's explicit.

Comment: @einpoklum ah I think now I get what you were saying. Naively I would expect the `using` to have similar effect as if you wrote `namespace x {} namespace x{}` in the global scope, but somehow it seems as if the `using` causes you to have two "different" `sub`  namespaces

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894400/resolving-ambiguity-with-using-declaration, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912330/rationale-behind-using-namespace-behavior

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: But I would still not be able to refer to it as `sub::f`. So that doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 5):

[namespace.udir] says (emphasis mine):

> -2- A *using-directive* specifies that the names in the nominated namespace can be used in the scope in which the *using-directive* appears after the *using-directive*. **During unqualified name lookup (6.4.1), the names appear
>   as if they were declared in the nearest enclosing namespace which contains both the *using-directive* and the nominated namespace.** *[Note:* In this context, “contains” means “contains directly or indirectly”. *— end note]*

In your example "the names in the nominated namespace" is just `foo::sub` because that's the only name declared in namespace `foo`, and the "nearest enclosing namespace which contains both the *using-directive* and the nominated namespace" is the global namespace.  So `foo::sub` appears (for the purposes of name lookup) as though it were in the global namespace, like this:

```
namespace sub {
int f();
} // namespace sub 

namespace bar {
namespace sub {

int g()  {
    return sub::f() + 1;
}

} // namespace sub 
} // namespace bar
```

Now it should be more obvious that `sub::f` won't find anything. Name lookup for `sub::f` starts by looking for `sub`. It doesn't find it in the enclosing namespace (which is `bar::sub`) so it looks in the next innermost enclosing scope (which is `bar`) and there it finds `sub`. At that point name lookup for `sub` stops, it doesn't look in the global namespace where it would find `foo::sub` made visible by the *using-directive*.

The next step of name lookup tries to find `f` in the scope it found for `sub`, but there's no `f` in the namespace it found, so name lookup fails.

Using-directives do not work like adding a using-declaration for every member of the namespace, they are "weaker" than using-declarations. The reason for that is so that names really declared in a namespace take priority over names simply made visible by a using-directive. [rodrigo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44950817/981959) to a related question explains that in more detail.

Comment: 1. This part of the standard takes away my stated intention of focusing the search on what's in `foo` over what's in `bar`. This is rather annoying. It would be mitigated if 2.  I would still expect `sub::f()` to work in the "as-if" code snippet you wrote. Call it "Namespace-match failure is not an error" if you will.

Comment: 2. but that's not how name lookup works, it always stops at the first match (http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.unqual#1). If you have a class `::foo::bar` and one of its members calls `bar::oops()` instead of `bar::ops()` (i.e. a simple typo) you don't want the compiler to consider `::bar::oops()` just because there's another `bar` scope elsewhere in the program.

Comment: Let me modify that example slightly, because you're backing me into a corner which isn't covered by the standard... Suppose the class `bar` isn't in `::foo` but in `baz::foo`. Now, in your example, if some method says `using namespace baz; ::bar::oops();` - then yes, I would definitely want the compiler to use `::baz::bar::oops()`. The `using namespace` is me giving the compiler a hint as to what I'm interested in.

Comment: Obviously if you say `::bar::oops()` then you aren't referring to the class `::baz::foo::bar`, so I don't see how that's relevant. If you use a fully-qualified name starting with `::` then name lookup starts at `::` not the innermost scope, which is the case I was talking about. This discussion seems pointless, name lookup stops at the first match, for good reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I think the relevant part of the standard that prevents what you are trying to do is this:

> 6.3.10 Name hiding [[basic.scope.hiding]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.scope.hiding)
>   ...
>   [4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.scope.hiding#4) During the lookup of a name qualified by a namespace name, *declarations that would otherwise be made visible by a using-directive can be hidden by declarations with the same name in the namespace containing the using-directive*;

You have `sub` in both `foo` and `bar` namespaces. And the `sub` in `bar` is hiding the `sub` in `foo` in spite of the `using` directive. And that is the reason why the `f()` in `foo::sub` is also not visible.

Comment: "*can* be"? Isn't that weird wording for the standard? Also - when we're talking about namespaces, why isn't the "hiding"  only restricted to what's actually in the namespace?

Comment: @einpoklum: Yes. It occurs in multiple places in that section.

Comment: @P.W: If it "_can_ be", doesn't that mean it "doesn't necessarily have to be"?

Comment: @einpoklum, _'If it "can be", doesn't that mean it "doesn't necessarily have to be"?'_ No, not necessarily. ["Essentially, can denotes capability or capacity, and may denotes permission or opportunity.](https://chambers.co.uk/search/?query=can&title=21st) It is used here in the "it's possible to do that" not the "it may be possible" sense.

Comment: The hiding is restricted to what's in the namespace, which is why this part of the standard isn't relevant in this case. This rule would only apply if there was a `bar::sub::sub` namespace. In that case `bar::sub::sub` would hide `foo::sub`.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Okay. So it is better to delete this answer then?

Answer (score 0):

An answer to your first point:
What happens when you add to your program a:

```
namespace sub
{
    int f();
}
```

What should now the compiler choose:
 ::sub::f() or (using ::foo::)sub::f() ?

Comment: Whichever. Or it can give me some error or warning. If I caused the ambiguity it is "on me" to live with the consequences.